# Putting additional data to $routeProvider templateUrl request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angularjs-routing, ng-view

I want add to add some headers to the requests for fetching templates so I can reject non-angularjs requests and respond with an error.

However it seems that it's only possible using `$http` and it seems like terrible waste to reimplement a mechanism similar to the one `templateUrl` provides.

Here's my sample router:

```
siteApp.config([ '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/user', {
                controller : 'UserController',
            }).when('/link', {
                templateUrl : '/user/index.json'
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        } ]);
```

edit: if it helps, I'm trying to get my ZendFramework2 API to detect it, but it fails to recognize the `XmlHttpRequest`

Comment: Personally I suggest you use `ui-route` which can inject $http into template loading by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to load those template at the `run` phase of angular.
That will be putted inside `$templateCache` provider and when you request the same template for second time it will fetch directly from `$templateCache` itself.

**CODE**

```
//get the templates with headers in application run phase.
app.run(['$templateCache', '$q', '$http', function($templateCache, $q, $http) {
    var promises = [];
    $http.get('partials/views/template1.html', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined //here you can add multiple header and get the template
        },
        cache: $templateCache
    });
    $http.get('partials/views/template2.html', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': undefined //here you can add multiple header and get the template
        },
        cache: $templateCache
    });
}]);
```

Hope this could help you. Thanks.

Comment: Very nice solution. Is there a way it could break? E.g. the cache would get flushed somehow?

Comment: Sure, you can do `$ templateCache. removeAll();` that will clear all the the cache of $templateCache